# Inserting Symbols into my graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

I am trying to show two braids are equivalent, I have my code as follows

```
\begin{figure}[htb]

      \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \braid [line width=.4mm] a_2^{-1} a_1^{-1} a_2^{-1} a_1^{-1};
        \end{tikzpicture}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \braid [line width=.4mm] a_1^{-1} a_2^{-1} a_1^{-1} a_2^{-1};
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Represents how two $3$-braids can be equivalent.}
\end{figure}
```

which gives me my two braids side by side, only problem is I can't get my equivalence sign inbetween them, I want this guy: ~ to be centered in the middle of the two braids.

Can anyone help?

Comment: don't put a blank line between them, that is a paragraph break, put $\sim$ (or perhaps more semantically sound but the tikzpictures inside the math as well)

Comment: or even don't separate the tikzpicture, but rather use the options `at` and `name` of the package that in combination with the `positioning` library allows you to achieve the goal.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Could you explain this further please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an implementation that roughly follows @ClaudioFiandrino's suggestion

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{braids}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \braid [line width=.4mm] (first) at (0,0) a_2^{-1} a_1^{-1} a_2^{-1} a_1^{-1};
        \node [right =3.5em of first] (equiv) {$\sim$};
        \braid [line width=.4mm] (second) at (3,0) a_1^{-1} a_2^{-1} a_1^{-1} a_2^{-1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Represents how two $3$-braids can be equivalent.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

From the [`braids` documentation](http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/braids/braids_doc.pdf):

> The (optional) name acts a little like the name of a TikZ node. When
>   it is specified, the routine that renders the braid also saves certain
>   coordinates as if they were node anchors. Specifically, coordinate
>   nodes are placed at the centre of the braid diagram and at the ends of
>   each strand. The centre has the label `name`, [...]

By naming the first braid `first`, we can then place the `node` with `$\sim$` relative to `first` using the `positioning` syntax (`right =(<len>) of name`, where the length is optional and `name` is the name of the `node` relative to which you wish to place the current node), and the result will be vertically centered, since the `name` for the `\braid` is located at the center of the diagram.

Finally, since the `\braid`s are now in the same `tikzpicture`, I've placed them at differing coordinates so that they don't sit on top of each other by using the `at (coordinate)` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

An example would have been nice. I did not even know of the existence of the braid library before. Nevertheless here an attempt.

I struggled with the positioning a bit as the braid does not have a "east" node which lets you easily position things, so some manual work was required.

First I calculated a node half way between the start and and of the 3rd braid. Then I shifted that node 1cm.
Then I create a coordinate (b2) at the start of the 3rd braid and shift this 2cm to the right.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{braids}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\braid[name=b1] [line width=.4mm] a_2^{-1} a_1^{-1} a_2^{-1} a_1^{-1};
\node[xshift=1cm] (equal) at ($(b1-3-s)!0.5!(b1-3-e)$) {=};
\coordinate[xshift=1cm] (b2) at (b1-3-s);
\braid at (b2) [line width=.4mm] a_1^{-1} a_2^{-1} a_1^{-1} a_2^{-1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Represents how two $3$-braids can be equivalent.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It feels like a somewhat hackish solution, but works...

[image]

Comment: more from @AndrewStacey can be found here http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files